# Why don't margin-top: auto and margin-bottom:auto work the same as their left and right counterparts?

Tags: css

If I set the CSS margin properties of a div like so:

```
div { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

I get a div which is centered horizontally in the page, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/T8Hnb/).

However, if I change the CSS to this:

```
div { margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; }
```

my div is not vertically centered. I don't need to know a workaround ([plenty of solutions](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) [are available](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html)) but I would like to know the reason for this behaviour. Why don't margin-top and margin-bottom work in the same way? What am I missing?

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2017 or later, the answer now seems to be: they do, but only if you're using flexbox. If your parent element has `display: flex;` then `margin: auto;` on a child will center it horizontally _and_ vertically.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is the spec says so.

> #### 10.6.2 Inline replaced elements, block-level replaced elements in normal flow, 'inline-block' replaced elements in normal flow and floating replaced elements
>
> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins

Comment: does padding act the same regarding top/bottom ?

Comment: @sam: The used value is *always* zero for `padding: auto` on any side.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are talking about auto margins within a Flexbox..

The reason that `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto` will center an item is because the width by default is 100% of the available container for a block element.

The height on the other hand attempts to fill as little as the space as possible, so `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` as `auto` will default to 0. BUT, if your element is within an element with a fixed height, then `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will be able to calculate the center based on that height.

Ex. http://jsfiddle.net/jwz76e3g/24/