# why wont {margin:auto;} give an auto margin at the top and bottom?

Tags: css, margin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't margin-top: auto and margin-bottom:auto work the same as their left and right counterparts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775273/why-dont-margin-top-auto-and-margin-bottomauto-work-the-same-as-their-left-an)

when you use `{margin:auto;}` it gives you an auto margin either side of the object, but you dont get them on the top and the bottom of the object, why is this ?

For instance if i wanted to centralise an item in the middle of the page i would have to use `{width:250px; height:250px; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -125px; margin-left: -125px;}`

Surly margin auto should handle this for both the top/bottom & left/right margin ?

Comment: That's one of those questions us veterans always had in mind but suppressed it as "meh, doesn't matter" +1.

Comment: When you use `margin:auto;` are you using `position` too ? It depends on `position` and without it.

Comment: @sarfra - No, just one or the other

Comment: This is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775273/why-dont-margin-top-auto-and-margin-bottomauto-work-the-same-as-their-left-an, though the accepted answer is just "the spec says so" -- to set margin-top and margin-bottom to 0 when auto is used. (still +1 from me because *why?*)

Comment: @BoltClock: because it would be incredibly useful to have margin:auto work vertically like it does horizontally. Think of all the questions posted here about how to vertically center content in a div. Centering a fluid-height block inside another block can be quite a challenge.

Comment: @Faust: That other question also asks *why* - perhaps you should +1 it as well if not already. (I deleted my earlier comment as I realized it made no sense, and upvoted the question as well.)