# What is the rationale behind margin-top: auto and margin-bottom: auto amounting to 0 margin?

Tags: css, margin, vertical-alignment, w3c

Since `margin-right: auto` and `margin-left: auto` center an element horizontally, I would expect their vertical counterparts to behave in the same way.

Yet I understand this does not happen, as per CSS specs:

> #### 10.6.2 Inline replaced elements, block-level replaced elements in normal flow, 'inline-block' replaced elements in normal flow and floating replaced elements
>
> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.

Also applies to block elements:

> #### 10.6.3 Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible'
>
> This section also applies to block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' does not compute to 'visible' but has been propagated to the viewport.
>
> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.

Now what I would like to know, is the rationale behind this decision/behavior.

What I'm searching for is understanding and conviction. I don't think a vague explanation  would do it, yet any contribution is welcome.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775273/why-dont-margin-top-auto-and-margin-bottomauto-work-the-same-as-their-left-an except that question doesn't seem concerned with *why the spec says so*.

Comment: I'm thinking this has largely to do with collapsing margins; there's no way you could have a non-zero value without causing margins to collapse in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Note that there are obscure cases where margin-top:auto and margin-bottom:auto do resolve to non-zero equidistant vertical margins. See http://jsfiddle.net/aVbyK/ . Sadly these cases are too obscure to be much use. Also, in terms of vertical margins comparable behaviour to margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto making equidistant horizontal margins, you're quoting the wrong piece of the spec. It should be section 10.6.3 Block-level non-replaced elements in normal flow when 'overflow' computes to 'visible', not 10.6.2. Can't really shed any light on the rationale, though.

Comment: Aha... That's not so obscure! I can see it being useful. Thanks for the example you gave on jsfiddle.
So, if an element is absolutely positioned in relation to the parent element, using *both* top and bottom, yet it's height is defined and is less then the height of the parent element minus the top and bottom offsets, then the margin property will be used to determine it's vertical alignement in relation to the parent, and margin:auto will result in a vertically centered element.
True, it sounds complicated, yet it's clear on jsfiddle. Thanks again!

Comment: Because wc3 is 1-dimensional with height as an after thought.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> Aha... That's not so obscure! I can see it being useful. Thanks for the example you gave on jsfiddle.
>
> So, if an element is absolutely positioned in relation to the parent element, using both `top` and `bottom`, yet it's `height` is defined and is less then the height of the parent element minus the `top` and `bottom` offsets, then the `margin` property will be used to determine it's vertical alignment in relation to the parent, and `margin:auto` will result in a vertically centered element.
>
> True, it sounds complicated, yet it's clear on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aVbyK/).

For example, this CSS:

```
.inner { 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; bottom: 20px; left:0; right:0px;
  padding:0; border:0;
  margin:auto;
  height:20px; width:50px;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div class=outer>
    <div class=inner>Text</div>
</div>
```