# margin: auto auto

Tags: css, centering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't margin-top: auto and margin-bottom:auto work the same as their left and right counterparts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775273/why-dont-margin-top-auto-and-margin-bottomauto-work-the-same-as-their-left-an)
>   [What is the rationale behind margin-top: auto and margin-bottom: auto amounting to 0 margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386739/what-is-the-rationale-behind-margin-top-auto-and-margin-bottom-auto-amounting)

Why doesn't `margin: auto auto;` add vertical centering? Shouldn't the auto keyword tell the browser to split the margins equally between the top and bottom? I was under the impression that was what it does for left and right margins.

Comment: The primary question is open-ended. And there is a lot of discussion on SO and around the web on vertical centering of elements.

Comment: @BoltClock, any reason you didn't close as dupe?

Comment: @zzzzBov hasn't been up for 5 mins.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I've been quite torn on which question to use as the canonical dupe. One asks a much deeper question (why was it made this way?), the other is older but simply a more general question. Maybe I'll take this to meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately it's a w3c spec -

> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.

It does seem like it would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

The `auto` keyword should do whatever is defined in the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins), which happens to be:

> If 'margin-top', or 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', their used value is 0.